# Вывод строк из списка с ограничением по длине строки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список строк, мне нужно выводить эти строки с условием, что в сумме их длина не больше числа N. Если в сумме длина двух строк больше N, то вывод начинается заново. Т.е. длина каждого вывода не может быть больше N.
Пример для числа N = 8

```py
['abc','defg','hijkl','mnopqr']
Вывод:
'abc' , 'defg'
'hijkl'
'mnopqr'
```

Comment: Нужно так нужно. Выводите.

Answer (score 1):

```
l  = ['abc', 'defg', 'hijkl', 'mnopqr']
_d = 0
_l = []

for i in l:
    if (_d + len(i)) < 8:
        _l.append(i)
        _d = _d + len(i)
    else:
        print(_l)
        _l = [i,]
        _d = len(i)
if _l: 
    print(_l)
```

---

```
['abc', 'defg']
['hijkl']
['mnopqr']
```